# Which is the best license to release a framework?

Tags: ios, licensing, report

I'm developing a report engine for iOS devices which uses CoreData.

I wish release it with an open source license, but I don't know which is the best to choose.

These are the requisites that I need to be satisfied:

- The engine could be used in commercial and non-commercial apps
- The developer that use the engine must give public credits into the app
- If the developer makes changes to the engine must release it (and only it) in a public repository or must send them to me to integrate them into a newer release.

Have you some suggestion?

Comment: This is not a legal advice site. Talk to a lawyer.

Comment: thank you Marc, but having some suggestion it's useful to have an idea, actually i don't know any OpenSource license and how they works.

Comment: This is a forum for developers on programming topics (http://stackoverflow.com/faq). You should probably contact someone from openSource initiative http://www.opensource.org/lists, and good luck with you opensource engine.

Comment: Thank you marcolinux i've sent an email to osi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [this license(LGPL v3)](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl.html) right for you.

Comment: just not sure about the second criteria

Comment: I've seen also the Mozilla Public License on the Opensource site. It could be a good alternative to LGPL?

Comment: The more rare license the greater the chance that it will scare away developers. I have not met with MPL before.

Comment: After a first evaluation i've choose to release it with LGPL v3 license. I will only ask to give credits into the apps. Thank you!

Comment: @komelgman: Please see the GPL FAQ: [I want to get credit for my work. I want people to know what I wrote. Can I still get credit if I use the GPL?](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#IWantCredit) - GPL v3 (which is extended by LGPL v3) is pretty clear about that, binary forms are form of the work as well. See Section 4 and 5 of GPL.

Answer (score 1):

As Marc B said, you really should talk to a lawyer. In the meantime, you may want to visit http://www.opensource.org/ for some studying and Larry Rosen wrote an excellent book on the topic: http://www.rosenlaw.com/oslbook.htm .